# Best way to conditionally link frameworks based on their availability in Xcode using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, frameworks

I'm developing an objective-c framework based off Cocoa touch and am looking at other frameworks for parsing data, both for JSON and XML.

I want to be as easy for the developer using to use my framework out of the box and am wondering what the best way to include third party frameworks conditionally. I want to give credit where credit is due, so I don't want to include the other projects with the distribution, but I'd like the developer be able to add a framework (or even just a bunch of classes) like SBJson or Touch XML and have my codebase to see the included codebase and use it with the added functionality it provides. Enabling the framework through some kind of config file, or in the project settings is also an option, but is less ideal.

1. What is the best way to do this with the compiler settings? I have
   seen a lot of developers switching included frameworks from
   "Required" to "Optional", but I don't think either SBJson or Touch
   XML are compiled down to or implemented using an objective-c
   framework package (.framework) or a C static library (.a) and thus
   wouldn't be able to take advantage of this.
2. How would one conditionally implement this in code? For instance
   SBJson's header is imported via a  `#import "SBJson.h"` compiler
   directive, but this will fail if the required header isn't found.

Comment: The "easiest" way would be to check for header include guards (you know, the whole #define HAS_MYHEADER_DECL thing Xcode will include when you make a c header), and do some conditional compiling based on that.  Of course, this is not reliable at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the .h but when using an object from it you need to call it with NSClassFromString

Comment: That would be a good way, but wouldn't LLVM/Xcode throw a error if the .h file isn't found.

Comment: Whoa! Nevermind. I see what you're getting at. Using NSClassFromString one can initialize the class using alloc and init, and the header file checking doesn't throw an error noting the class is not included. In other words, using NSClassFromString() completely bypasses the compile time import directives. Kind of like passing an instance using a message with id and sending messages to it. Magic! Thank you!